# installing opencv gives error unsported GCC version despite use of alternative

Tags: compiling, 17.04, gcc, g++, opencv

I'm trying to install opencv 3.1. I have downloaded opencv (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/archive/3.1.0.zip) and unzipped it.  Now according to various tutorials I should be able to compile it using

```
$cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON     -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF     -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules     -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python     -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
$make -j $(nproc)
```

This quickly fails with the following output:

```
$ make -j $(nproc)
[  0%] Automatic moc for target opencv_test_highgui
[  0%] Automatic moc for target opencv_test_cvv
[  0%] Automatic moc for target opencv_cvv
[  0%] Automatic moc for target example_cvv_cvv_demo
[  0%] Automatic moc for target opencv_highgui
[  1%] Built target opencv_cudev
[  1%] Built target numeric
[  2%] Built target libjasper
[  2%] Building NVCC (Device) object modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o
[  2%] Built target opencv_test_cvv_automoc
[  2%] Built target opencv_test_highgui_automoc
[  2%] Built target example_cvv_cvv_demo_automoc
[  2%] Built target opencv_cvv_automoc
[  2%] Built target opencv_highgui_automoc
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
In file included from /usr/include/cuda_runtime.h:78:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/usr/include/host_config.h:119:2: error: #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
 #error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!
  ^~~~~
[  3%] Built target multiview
[  3%] Built target correspondence

CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o.cmake:208 (message):
  Error generating
  /home/thijser/opencv-3.1.0/build/modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/./cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o


modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gpu_mat.cu.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2122: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So it says that I'm using the wrong version of gcc however I'm already using 4.9 via alternatives

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
There are 3 choices for the alternative gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc).

  Selection    Path              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/gcc-6     60        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/gcc-4.9   20        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/gcc-5     25        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/gcc-6     60        manual mode
```

Also here is the cmake output

```
$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON     -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF     -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules     -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python     -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 49 (409)
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   No package 'libgphoto2' found
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/thijser/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- CUDA detected: 8.0
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_21;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=compute_30
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/thijser/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python (found suitable version "3.5.3", minimum required is "2.7") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Found PythonInterp: /home/thijser/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3 (found suitable version "3.5.3", minimum required is "3.4") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Found apache ant 1.9.8: /usr/bin/ant
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "vtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- Found VTK ver. 6.3.0 (usefile: /usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/UseVTK.cmake)
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   YES
-- Glog:   YES
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5:   YES
-- CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver for reconstruction API is required.
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- HDF5: Using hdf5 compiler wrapper to determine C configuration
-- HDF5:   YES
-- The protocol buffer compiler and libprotobuf were found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- CERES support is disabled. Ceres Solver for reconstruction API is required.
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 4.10.0-26-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.7.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 6.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):
--     Linker flags (Debug):
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so dc1394 xine v4l1 v4l2 avcodec avformat avutil swscale /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/libhdf5.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so correspondence multiview numeric glog gflags vtkRenderingOpenGL vtkImagingHybrid vtkIOImage vtkCommonDataModel vtkCommonMath vtkCommonCore vtksys vtkCommonMisc vtkCommonSystem vtkCommonTransforms vtkCommonExecutionModel vtkDICOMParser vtkIOCore /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so vtkmetaio /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so vtkImagingCore vtkRenderingCore vtkCommonColor vtkFiltersExtraction vtkFiltersCore vtkFiltersGeneral vtkCommonComputationalGeometry vtkFiltersStatistics vtkImagingFourier vtkalglib vtkFiltersGeometry vtkFiltersSources vtkInteractionStyle vtkRenderingLOD vtkFiltersModeling vtkIOPLY vtkIOGeometry vtkFiltersTexture vtkRenderingFreeType /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so vtkftgl vtkIOExport vtkRenderingAnnotation vtkImagingColor vtkRenderingContext2D vtkRenderingGL2PS vtkRenderingContextOpenGL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgl2ps.so vtkRenderingLabel dl m pthread rt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so tbb atomic cudart nppc nppi npps cufft -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libjasper
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann hdf imgproc ml reg surface_matching video viz cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping dnn fuzzy imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect plot ts xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cvv datasets java rgbd stereo structured_light superres tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow sfm stitching
--     Disabled:                    world contrib_world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 python2 python3 matlab
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.7.1)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.7.1)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so)
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.3.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0209)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.6.28)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.7)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 2.2.0)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 57.64.101)
--       format:                    YES (ver 57.56.101)
--       util:                      YES (ver 55.34.101)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.12.3) / libv4l2 (ver 1.12.3)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        YES (ver 1.2.6)
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.4 interface 9005)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /home/thijser/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.3.2)
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 8.0)
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
--     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 21 30 35
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            30
--     Use fast math:               NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/thijser/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/thijser/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python (ver 3.5.3)
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/thijser/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.3)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /home/thijser/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.8)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.13)
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/thijser/opencv-3.1.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/thijser/opencv-3.1.0/build
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

edit output of

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin
total 20900
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  9913472 sep 14  2016 cicc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 mrt 27 14:19 crt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      711 jan 20 20:25 g++
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      711 jan 20 19:48 gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       40 jan 20 20:25 libcuinj64.so -> ../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuinj64.so.8.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   245680 sep 14  2016 nvcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 jan 20 20:25 nvcc.profile -> /etc/nvcc.profile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11226584 sep 14  2016 nvprof
```

Where gcc contains the following:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/gcc
#!/bin/sh

# Check for g++ to avoid using different versions of gcc and g++ on systems
# with both g++-4.X and gcc-4.Y but not g++-4.Y installed.

prog=false
if g++-5 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    prog=gcc-5
elif g++-4.9 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    prog=gcc-4.9
elif g++-4.8 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    prog=gcc-4.8
elif clang-3.8 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is available." >&2
    echo "       Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead." >&2
    exit 1
else
    echo "ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found." >&2
    echo "       Use 'nvcc -ccbin <compiler>' to specify a host compiler." >&2
    exit 1
fi

exec $prog "$@"
```

and g++ contains

```
$ cat /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/bin/g++
#!/bin/sh

# Check for g++ to avoid using different versions of gcc and g++ on systems
# with both g++-4.X and gcc-4.Y but not g++-4.Y installed.

prog=false
if g++-5 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    prog=g++-5
elif g++-4.9 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    prog=g++-4.9
elif g++-4.8 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    prog=g++-4.8
elif clang-3.8 --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found, but clang-3.8 is available." >&2
    echo "       Use 'nvcc -ccbin clang-3.8' to use that instead." >&2
    exit 1
else
    echo "ERROR: No supported gcc/g++ host compiler found." >&2
    echo "       Use 'nvcc -ccbin <compiler>' to specify a host compiler." >&2
    exit 1
fi

exec $prog "$@"
```

edit edit: adding the -D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin gcc-4.9" flag resulted in

```
compilation until 32% as which point it fails because 
[ 32%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_test_dnn
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::GetTypeName() const'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageFactory::InternalRegisterGeneratedFile(char const*, void (*)(std::string const&))'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteString(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::FindFileByName(std::string const&) const'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr::AssignWithDefault(std::string const*, google::protobuf::internal::ArenaStringPtr)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::ReadBytes(google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream*, std::string*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::Message::InitializationErrorString() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_dnn.dir/build.make:259: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_dnn' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_dnn] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7156: recipe for target 'modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_dnn.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_dnn.dir/all] Error 2
[ 32%] Linking CXX executable ../../bin/opencv_perf_video
[ 32%] Built target opencv_perf_video
[ 32%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudaarithm.so
[ 32%] Built target opencv_cudaarithm
[ 32%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudawarping.so
[ 32%] Built target opencv_cudawarping
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

elsewhere it is suggested that this problem can occur if opencv 4.9 is used to install this but that would break cuda again. (and make clean or rm build -r didn't solve t he issue either)

Comment: Since you are building with CUDA, it may be using versions of gcc/g++ explicitly linked to the CUDA bin directory (bypassing anything configured via `update-alternatives`) - please add a long listing of that dir (e.g. `ls -l /usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin`) to your question

Comment: Thanks - so are the `gcc` and `g++` executables in that dir just wrapper scripts? if so, what do they contain?

Comment: And yes the gcc and g++ are nearly identical with only a small difference.

Comment: Thanks - there are a few suggestions here that you can try --> [gcc versions error when installing OpenCV 3.1.0](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6513) - I don't know which is best (or whether they all still apply in CUDA 8.0)

Comment: @steeldriver If I understand what they are doing correctly I would add CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin gcc-4.9" to the cmake command making for $ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE     -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local     -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON     -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF     -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules     -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python     -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON  CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin gcc-4.9" ..
 right? That doesn't work with the same result

Comment: Try `-D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-ccbin gcc-4.9"` (note the `-D`)

Comment: @steeldriver Ah yes I think that works (currently at 8% compiled), perhaps you can turn it into an answer?

Comment: Ugh now it breaks at 32% (see edit edit)